# retrieving digit from a string mysql

Tags: mysql

I've got a mysql database containing table "numbers" and entries

```
id | numberss
1 | 1,5,45
2 | 11,8,99
3 | 14, 15,84
4 | 1,58,47
```

How I have to write a mysql query, to retreive info only from those tables, which got number "1" in field "numberss" ? Not 11, not 15, only 1. Now I have:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE numberss LIKE '%1%'");
```

But of course it doesn't work how I want to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM numbers WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, numberss);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM numberss WHERE numberss 
LIKE  '%[^0-9]1[^0-9]%' 
or numberss like '1[^0-9]%'  
or numberss like '%[^0-9]1'
```

should work